# how to send push notification to a specific device without creating channels using parse.com?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

In my ios app, i am using **Parse.com** api 
 there are two view controllers, view controller 1 presents my friends fb profile photos.
View controller 2  presents  the Friends profile. now i want to send push notification to my selected friend whose FB id i have.
 can i target a friend with fb id without creating channel?

i am trying following code,

```
//View Controller 1

//Register current user after login

-(void)registerUserForPushNotification
{
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setObject:user forKey:@"Owner"];
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:CurrentUserFacebookId forKey:@"fbId"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}


//View controller 2
//Send Push notification to  friend
-(void)sendPushNotification
{

// get the PFUser object for current user
PFQuery *userQuery=[PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"fbId" equalTo:ClientFBId];//ClientFBId is my friend's FB id

// send push notification to the user
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"Owner" matchesQuery:userQuery];
PFPush *push = [PFPush new];
[push setQuery: pushQuery];
NSString *message=[[CurrentUserName stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:@"sent you ilu"];    
[push setData: @{ @"alert":message}]; 
[push sendPush: nil];
}
```

i have searched the docs. everything is fine. it even shows my push notification on parse.com. but it says "You sent this push notification to 0 recipients." on top of the push notification tab on parse.com.

any guesses whats wrong?

please note:- i am not sending push notification to all the friends but only one friend at a time. so i guess, i dont have to create a channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out every step mentioned in my question was correct. neither code had issue.
I noted that my app was not receiving device tokens on parse console.So i thought may be there's an issue with my certificate.

**Regenerated the certificate with push notification configured and created provisioning profile again.**

That got it working. Receiving device tokens on parse console now and getting push notifications.
here's the [link](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) for step by step instructions.
don't miss a single one.hope it helps you all !!!

Answer (score 0):

Parse lets you send push messages through either channels, or direct to installations (devices).

What's important to realise is that a single user may have multiple installations associated with them - for example, they might own an iPhone and an iPad. You will want to send the push message to both.

It is hard to tell from what you've posted what's going on, as you've merged two view controllers together. I assume that in your second view controller `user` is the user you are trying to send the push notification to? How are you obtaining the `PFUser` object that represents the friend? Maybe share that code and you might get some more help.

Comment: Yes you are right , "user" in second view controller is referred to my friend. and my question is how to obtain PFUser Object for my friend

Comment: ...again, share more of your code. What type of object is `user` if not a `PFUser`? How are you obtaining that `user` variable?

Comment: yes user is a PFUser object. and my question is how to obtain that user variable for my friend?

Comment: ...well, presumably you have an array of `PFUser` pointers that represent friends for each user? Or some other data structure in Parse? It sounds as if the problem isn't so much push messaging, as needing to review how Parse stores data. I'd suggest you check Parse's documentation and tutorials, as they cover a lot of this stuff in great detail.

Comment: well that cant be the answer. i think i made my question clear enough

Comment: how would you send a push notification to your facebook friend using parse? not all friends just 1 specific friend you want to send message to @lxt

Comment: *Assuming* that your Facebook friend has a) downloaded the same app, and b) has a corresponding `PFInstallation`, you just query Parse for their devices and send a push. If what you're asking is "how do you send a push to a Facebook friend" and that friend *hasn't* got the app or created an account in Parse...you can't.

Comment: yes, thats what i am asking for---> how to query for Friend's PFUser object. note:-i am storing friend's PFInstallation Object on parse.

Comment: Rather than using the `sendPush:` method use the `sendPushDataToQuery:withData:error:` one. This will return a `NSError` that will tell you exactly why the push didn't work.

Comment: error returns null . also i found that installation object is not created everytime my app runs but it replaces the previous installation object